# Minimise UI changes based on document in query change

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angularfire2

I am working on an Angular application with AngularFire that makes use of nested data. I currently have a single (nested) query to get the parent and its child data, but this results in Angular recreating the parent component each time one of the child data points updates.

The data is structured something like:

```
Fields
  - Stories
    - Comments
```

With the nested data placed in subcollections inside Firebase. A comment might therefore have a path like:

```
database/fields/fieldId/stories/storyId/comments/commentId
```

To create a field object (which is displayed in the UI), I'm making use of rxjs's switchMap as follows:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getField(this.fieldID).subscribe(field => this.field = field);
}

getField(id: any): Observable<Field> {
  return this.getItem<Field>(id, 'fields').pipe(
    switchMap(field => {
      const nextPath = `fields/${field.id}/stories`;
      return getStories(nextPath).pipe(tap(stories => field.stories = stories));
    })
  );
}

getStories(path: string): Observable<Story[]> {
  return this.getItems<Story>(path).pipe(
    switchMap(stories => {
      stories.map(story => {
        let nextPath = `${path}/${story.id}/comments`;
        return getComments(nextPath).pipe(tap(comments => field.comments = comments));
      });
    })
  );
}

getComments(path: string): Observable<Comment[]> {
  return this.getItems<Comment>(path).pipe(
    switchMap(comments => {
      comments.map(comment => getComments(nextPath));
    })
  );
}
```

Using the following getItem and getItems functions:

```
getItem<T>(id: string, collectionName: string): Observable<T> {
  return this.fireDb
    .collection<T>(collectionName)
    .doc<T>(id)
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map(item => this.itemFromDocument(item)));
}

getItems<T>(collectionName: string): Observable<T[]> {
  return this.fireDb
    .collection<T>(collectionName)
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map(items => items.map(item => this.itemFromCollection(item))));
}
```

Take note, this is simplified version of the actual code which includes limits, filters as well as a few more complex queries, so apologies if there are any errors above. Regardless, the database functions work and I can get a Field with its nested information using the calls.

The issue I've run into is that every time a single Comment is modified or added, the entire field is recreated which I assume triggers Angular to rebuild all the components relying on that Field. This results in things like input fields being cleared as their parent containers are recreated.

**My question is: What is the best way to structure these calls to avoid recreating the Field with each change?**

I have considered the following options:

1. Remove the nested switchMap calls. Instead, make each of these calls from the root of the function, and simply update the data as the calls complete.
2. Once the data is modified, identify only the data points that have been changed and update them individually.
3. Stop relying on list queries and somehow query the individual collection documents directly.
4. Close the initial subscription after receiving the data, then handle any changes locally.
5. Some combination of the above.

So, is there a suggested way to handle the above situation? I'd really appreciate any suggestions or advice!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I'm trying out:

1. Subscribe to get the Field the first time, then close the subscription.
2. Using the nested Field values, create individual observers for each document. These update the individual documents if changes are made to them.
3. Create a filtered query that listens for newly created documents (using something like https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1551) in any of the subcollections.

I'm still certain that there must be a more elegant solution. It's also very likely that this solution will have some long term negative effects, so I will add a comment if I run into anything.